# Teams in the same group in consecutive World Cups

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup

Argentina and Nigeria are in [group D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_D) of the 2018 Russia world cup. In Brazil's 2014 world cup these 2 teams were also [in the same group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_F) where Argentina lead the group and Nigeria qualified to the round of 16 as the second seed.

How many times have national teams played in the same group in back to back world cup tournaments? Please list the teams and the hosts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Brazil 1950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_1) and [Switzerland 1954](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_1): Brazil, Yugoslavia and Mexico
- [Switzerland 1954](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_1) and [Sweden 1958](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_2): France and Yugoslavia
- [Chile 1962](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_2) and [England 1966](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_2): Switzerland and West-Germany
- [Chile 1962](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_4) and [England 1966](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_3): Hungary and Bulgaria
- [Mexico 1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_2) and [West-Germany 1974](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1974_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_3): Sweden and Uruguay
- [West-Germany 1974](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1974_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_4) and [Argentina 1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_1): Italy and Argentina
- [Spain 1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_5) and [Mexico 1986](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_D): Spain and Northern Ireland
- [Italy 1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_B) and [USA 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_B): Cameroon and Soviet-Union/Russia
- [Italy 1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_E) and [USA 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_C): Spain and South Korea
- [USA 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_D) and [France 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_D): Nigeria and Bulgaria
- [USA 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_F) and [France 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_E): Netherlands and Belgium
- [France 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_C) and [South Korea and Japan 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A): France and Denmark
- [France 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_D) and [South Korea and Japan 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_B): Spain and Paraguay
- [South Korea and Japan 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_F) and [Germany 2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_B): Sweden and England
- [South Africa 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_H) and [Brazil 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_B): Chile and Spain
- [South Africa 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_H) and [Brazil 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_E): Switzerland and Honduras
- [South Africa 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_B) and [Brazil 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_F): Argentina and Nigeria
- [South Africa 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_D) and [Brazil 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_G): Germany and Ghana
- [Brazil 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_F) and [Russia 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_D): Argentina and Nigeria
- [Brazil 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_C) and [Russia 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_H): Colombia and Japan

**I believe this is a full list, but I might have missed a few. Feel free to edit the post if this is the case.**

A list of fun facts:

1. West-Germany and Switzerland, and Belgium and the Netherlands are the only neighboring countries who have had this happen.
2. If Nigeria would have qualified for the 2006 World Cup and were drawn in the same group as Argentina, they would be in the same group for five consecutive editions (they were both drawn in [Group F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_F) in 2002)

Comment: Please add link(s) to the sources you used so I can accept your answer

Comment: links are added (+ some extra fun facts)